# How to close the Intellij IDEA method parameter hint?

Tags: intellij-idea

After I installed the new version of intellij IDEA - 2016.3, there is a hint for the method parameters by default:

[image]

How to close it?

Thanks.

Comment: Type Cmd-Shift-A (Ctrl-Shift-A on windows), enter "parameter hint", find the "Appearance: show parameter name hints" entry and untoggle it. You can do that for basically everything in IntelliJ. The preferences dialog also has a search box on the top left.

Comment: @JBNizet Cool, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**Method 1**

Open Action Menu <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on Windows/Linux, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on Mac

Type `parameter hint`

You will see the toggle button on  **`"Appearance:Show parameter name hints"`**

Click to **`toggle`**

[image]

---

**Method 2**

```
Editor >> General >> Appearance >>
```

Uncheck **`"Show parameter name hints"`**

[image]